# Separators get lost when outputting in case of different number of characters in the field

Tags: c++

I have a problem with formatting. My program collects information about students, then it should output information that the user enters.
The conclusion should occur precisely in such columns (I mean tabulation and "||").
The problem is that with different sizes of fields, these separators "||" get lost for me and in general all this looks ugly. What can be done so that everything is displayed beautifully. even if the number of characters in some fields will not match?

How would I solve this problem on Pascal, for example:

```
write(first.surname:8:6);
```

Output:

```
Information you entered >                                                                                                        

 Surname <      Trump                           ||              Obama                                                         |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Group <        rz-1                            ||              rpds-5                                                        |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Course <       2                               ||              3                                                             |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Physics <      3                               ||              4                                                             |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Programming <  5                               ||              4                                                             |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Math <         3                               ||              3                                                             |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Name<  Donald                          ||              Barack                                                                |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Patronymic <   Donalldd                                ||              Bakkaa                                                |  
|                                                                                                                                
 Average <      3.66667                         ||              3.66667                                                       |  
|
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float sr_mark;
struct student
{
        char surname[21];
        char group[21];
        int course;
        int physics;
        int programming;
        int math;
        float mark;
        // Student Information
        char WorkersName[21]; // student name
        char JobTitle[21]; // middle name of student
};
 int main()
{
        setlocale(0, "");
    sr_mark = 0;
    cout << "\n";
        student first;
        cout << "\t" << "Enter information about the first student < " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter surname > ";
        cin >> first.surname;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter group > ";
        cin >> first.group;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter course > ";
        cin >> first.course;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter physics grade > ";
        cin >> first.physics;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter a programming grade > ";
        cin >> first.programming;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter math grade > ";
        cin >> first.math;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter student name > ";
    cin >> first.WorkersName;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter the middle name of the student > ";
    cin >> first.JobTitle;
    cout << "\n";
    sr_mark += first.math;
    sr_mark += first.programming;
    sr_mark += first.physics;
    sr_mark /= 3;
    first.mark = sr_mark;
    sr_mark = 0;

    cout << "\n";
        cout << "\t" << "Enter data about the second student < " << endl;
    cout << "\n";
        student *second = new student;
    cout << " Enter surname > ";
        cin >> second -> surname;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter group > ";
        cin >> second -> group;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter course > ";
        cin >> second -> course;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter physics grade > ";
        cin >> second -> physics;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter a programming grade > ";
        cin >> second -> programming;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter math grade > ";
        cin >> second -> math;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter student name > ";
        cin >> second -> WorkersName;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << " Enter the middle name of the student > ";
        cin >> second -> JobTitle;
    cout << "\n";
    sr_mark += second -> math;
    sr_mark += second -> programming;
    sr_mark += second -> physics;
    sr_mark /= 3;
    second -> mark = sr_mark;
    sr_mark = 0;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Information you entered >" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
        cout << " Surname < " << "\t" <<first.surname << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t" << second -> surname << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Group < " << "\t" <<first.group << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> group << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Course < " << "\t" <<first.course << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> course << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Physics < " << "\t" <<first.physics << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> physics << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Programming < " << "\t" <<first.programming << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> programming << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Math < " << "\t" <<first.math << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> math << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Name<" << "\t" <<first.WorkersName << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> WorkersName << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Patronymic < " << "\t" <<first.JobTitle << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> JobTitle << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";
    cout << " Average < " << "\t" <<first.mark << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" <<"\t\t" << second -> mark << "\t\t\t\t" << "||" << "\t\t\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Tab, '\t' will most probably not work. You should use ````std::setw```` defined in header file <iomanip>.

Comment: Any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned [the standard I/O manipulators in `<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip). Some of which can be used for formatting in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated task, there is no magic solution: you need to measure the sizes (in characters) of your fields, then add spaces accordingly, etc.
Not to mention the utf-8 problems you might have (size of string in bytes might not be the same as size in characters).

You could use `std::setw()` but that won't solve everything.

You are better to use a library.
If you have C++17 available, [tabulate](https://github.com/p-ranav/tabulate) seems a pretty neat solutions.
Might be overkill for your requirements ?

(Disclaimer: haven't used it myself.)